Is there a concern having a faster rise time in I2C fast mode than 20ns spec?
I have a rigid board system that contains a µC and sensor which measures I2C SDA/SCL rise time (400kHz) at 15-17ns between 10%-90% of the signal. When I look at the NXP spec, it states a minimum of 20ns for fast-mode (400kHz) operation. Is there a concern on being faster than the minimum spec? I can see why there would be concern if I was slower, but can't quite grasp what the repercussions are for being faster.

Which voltage bus and what value pull-ups? Basically, how do you even managed to end up with so fast rise time to begin with?

I should have been more clear. 1.8V with 2.21kΩ. The fast edge is probably due to the SIP driver + extremely small board + adv fab processes to lower parasitic effects.

2.21 kohms and around 16ns RC rise time from 10% to 90% would mean you have less than 4 pF of bus capacitance. That's less than typical value for two chip inputs, and much less than your scope probe which you have already connected to circuit. This is lower than should be possible and therefore something is not right.

I think there is a concern.
Not because in itself it is faster than allowed by I2C specification, but for the reason why, as it may reveal a problem, or it might be fine after you know why it is too fast.
Generally, for a properly sized pull-up resistor, you very rarely end up with faster rise time than allowed by specs.
There is a possibility that the pull-up resistor is sized incorrectly, it is too strong, and there might be too much current flowing, and that may make it hard to reach low enough voltage on bus - unless chip specific specifications say the currents and voltages are fine even if they are outside of specifications for I2C standard.
Another possibility is that for example you forgot to configure the MCU (FPGA, whatever host you have) pins correctly to open-drain output mode, and the pins are in push-pull mode.
Or, the bus is very short and there is very few devices and very little capacitance, so the rise time just happens to be extremely fast.
The reason why the I2C specification defines the rise time must be slower than 20ns is better EMC compatibility. Slower signal transitions mean higher impedance driver and less reflections on unterminated bus ends. Time of signal flight and reflections can be easily seen on bus when transitions are extremely fast.
Edit :
For that 16ns rise time from 10% to 90% and resistance of 2.21 kohms, the capacitance should be less than 4pF, which is much less than what a typical oscilloscope probe adds capacitive load to the circuit when probing, so something is not right.
I2C uses 30% to 70% specification for 20ns rise time, which means even 11pF with 2.21 kohms should be enough, and evem then, a typical scope probe alone should have more than that.

This is a bit of a mystery. You can find numerous 'official' non-answers in forums from the likes of NXP and TI, basically they say to follow the specification. There is speculation that it could be for EMI reasons (doesn't make a lot of sense- the fall times are faster) or because the fast mode devices include ST and spike circuitry that doesn't like really fast rise time edges- or that early devices had issues and they may have fixed it (more plausible).
In any case, you can increase the pullup resistor values to slow the waveform and conform to the specifications (accounting for probe capacitance in your measurement), gaining ease of mind and somewhat reduced power consumption.

If it is outside I2C specs then it can't be called I2C - The thing is, there may be something wrong like a push-pull MCU output, so I would say there is a concern, and it has to be investigated if it is an issue or not.

@Justme Or just conform to the specification in all respects and sleep well. That's why we have such specs- so things will be guaranteed to be interoperable. Maybe it's an odd effect that affects 10% of the devices at some temperature extreme. Maybe it always works with supplier A and usually, but not always, B.

Is there any concern for \$t_R<20~ns\$.
Consider -3 dB BW = 0.35/T (10~90%) = 70 MHz.
Just above, this is the FM band where emission regulations are tighter due to crøsstalk interference to FM receivers.
This is the only reason for this specification.

Could be, but then it explains only Fast Mode 20ns specs. The Standard Mode and FM-Plus Mode allows for faster rise/fall times, as they are unspecified.

Unspecified is not a spec nor an easemment unlike an FCC failure trying to go faster

Perhaps the 400k rate permits cost reductions on cable and balun costs to meet EMC.

In any case slew rate is RC dependent is easily adjustable and you certainly don't need 70 MHz BW for Fm+
